# How do I split excel column data into TWO columns with Blue Prism

Tags: excel, blueprism, rpa

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has various columns with their respective data. I need to take column "A", and split the example text "[11111] Dog" into TWO columns: "A" that now has "[11111]", and "B" that now has "Dog". Is there a way to do this within Blue Prism?

I have already used an action to gather the data into a collection, but am unsure of the next steps to execute what is desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you write the `TextToColumn` function in BP. I am trying as well, but is not working. This is how I am doing it.

```
Dim wb, ws, range, excel as Object

wb = GetInstance(handle)
ws = GetWorkbook(handle, WorkbookName).ActiveSheet.Range(cellref,cellref).Activate()
excel= ws.Application

range = ws().Selection.TextToColumns(OtherChar, Other)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Technically... if its not working its not a solution... but in your case OP might get new ideas from your attempt. Therefor, this "almost" answer may stay imho. Get it updated once it works (if joint effort.. refer to helper/OP, etc.). Tip... use ctrl-k for code formatting and ">" for the yellow box ..And finish the tour ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to use excel vbo object. 
Add an action with code stage, write code to split the columns with text to columns .
If you want to go with your collection , loop through collection and use utility strings object and split text action .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so any particular command exists for this type of separation in any rpa tool whether is Blue Prism or Ui Path, though I had developed a robot for this kind of work in G1ANT.
Code,

```
    xlsx.open ♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Desktop\try.xlsx
    for ♥n from 1 to 100 step 1
    xlsx.getvalue row ♥n colname a result ♥text
   ♥list⟦⟧=♥text
   xlsx.setvalue value ♥list⟦1:5⟧ row ♥n colname a
   xlsx.setvalue value ♥list⟦6:10⟧ row ♥n colname b
   end
   xlsx.close
```

You can change the total number of columns and separation point according to your need.